What happens to a sparse file's holes when the space is needed?
The scenario
Let's say you have a 1GB sparse file in a 2 GB filesystem and the sparse file is taking only 0.1 GB of space.
The question(s)
I guess you would have 1.9 GB to store data on disk, is that right?
If there's actually 1.9 GB of free space in disk, what if I stored 1.5 GB outside the sparse file, leaving only 0.4 GB of free space (1.5 GB outside the sparse file + 0.1 GB of the sparse file)? Would that mean that even if I see the sparse file as 1GB I would only be able to store 0.5 GB in total inside it (the 0.1 GB in use + 0.4 GB available)?
What would the OS do in this case?
Thoughts
If the above is true, using a sparse file sounds nice because of the saved space, but let's say I'm using this file as a storage point (loop device) and I want to count on that space, I guess using the sparse file wouldn't be a good idea because in case I needed the whole 1 GB I wouldn't be able to use it. I may be better off using a non sparse file.

You may be confusing preallocated and sparse.

@pipe What do you mean? Maybe expand a little on the comment?

@loco.loop Most modern POSIX systems allow you to pre-allocate space for a file without writing to it yet (the normal term of art is ‘unwritten extents’). This is very different from a sparse file, it ensures the space is reserved (though this is not always the same as usable for multiple reasons), so in your example if that 1 GB file was preallocated, you could only store 1 GB of additional data on the filesystem (actually a bit less for a bunch of other reasons).

@AustinHemmelgarn Do you have a link on how to do this? Sounds interesting. How stable/safe is it? I want it for backups.

@AustinHemmelgarn Example: fallocate -l 10G gentoo_root.img (from StackOverflow). However I'm not sure how safe/stable it is yet...

@loco.loop For non-CoW filesystems, it’s 100% reliable. For CoW filesystems it will work in a majority of cases as long as the filesystem is not completely full.

Ok. I don’t really know what a CoW filesystem is. Is ext4 non-CoW?

I forgot to @AustinHemmelgarn... you might not get a notification?

@loco.loop ‘CoW’ is short for copy-on-write, it’s a particular approach to data safety and update atomicity. BTRFS and ZFS are the major options on Linux for CoW filesystems. The issue with preallocation there is that writing new data still needs a bit more space to actually write the data to initially beyond the reserved space, so it can sometimes not work even if it would on a ‘regular’ filesystem like ext4 or XFS.


Would that mean that even if I see the sparse file as 1GB I would only be able to store 0.5 GB in total inside it (the 0.1 GB in use + 0.4 GB available)?

Yes.

What would the OS do in this case?

If you try to use more than the available free space, it will report that there's no space left:
% dd if=/dev/zero of=100MB.bin bs=1024 count=102400 # 100 MB image to work on
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 4.9645 s, 21.1 MB/s
% ls -sh 100MB.bin
101M 100MB.bin
% mkfs -t ext4 -q 100MB.bin
% mkdir 100MB
% sudo mount 100MB.bin 100MB
% sudo chown $USER 100MB -R

% truncate -s 1TB 100MB/foo  # A 1 TB sparse file
% dd if=/dev/zero of=100MB/bar bs=1024 count=51200 # But something else is using 50 MB
51200+0 records in
51200+0 records out
52428800 bytes (52 MB, 50 MiB) copied, 2.01964 s, 26.0 MB/s
% dd if=/dev/zero of=100MB/foo bs=1024 skip=102400 count=102400 conv=notrunc
dd: error writing '100MB/foo': No space left on device
31931+0 records in
31930+0 records out
32696320 bytes (33 MB, 31 MiB) copied, 1.64666 s, 19.9 MB/s
% du -h --apparent-size 100MB/foo; du -h 100MB/foo
932G    100MB/foo
32M 100MB/foo


If the above is true, using a sparse file sounds nice because of the saved space, but let's say I'm using this file as a storage point (loop device) and I want to count on that space, I guess using the sparse file wouldn't be a good idea because in case I needed the whole 1 GB I wouldn't be able to use it. I may be better off using a non sparse file.

That's something for which you'll have to do the risk assessment and decide for yourself. It's a balancing act. If you want to be absolutely sure you'll have the space, then you'll have to reserve the space in advance, and not use a sparse file.

Thanks for the answer! A couple of follow up questions. I might do two comments for two different types of questions.  (1) The skip option in dd, does it mean to start writing at that location? And would that mean that that there would be a "hole" representing the first 100MB? (2) Why is conv=notrunc needed? (3) I don't have the -q option in mkfs, is it quiet mode? Shouldn't it go before -t?

I'm adding an answer, similar to yours but with extra information checking the sizes in different moments. Also adding a note about mkfs, that makes the file sparse.


yes. 2) without it, dd truncates the file, so it won't be 1TB any longer but (size of hole + bytes written). 3) yes, I added the -q because I didn't want to copy that output, should have added it outside of -t ext4)


The other follow up. My use case is creating filesystem files for backup in a large hard drive. Moving those around seems easy enough between HDs. My concern would be to write 3T of zeros (not sparse file) because I wouldn't want to unnecessarily wear the hard drive. Is there another way to create a non sparse file without writing to it, conceptually I would not write but wouldn't care for the contents until I write stuff inside. Or perhaps, would you think creating partitions would be a better way to go? The filesystem files feel more flexible...

I think ZFS zvols are a good fit for this use case.

I haven’t used zfs before. It seems a bit of an overkill, maybe? Could you please elaborate on why you feel it would be a good fit? (My use case is a 8T external usb hard drive, I want to do backups for 2 computers (maybe 3 in the future), one would need a 3T space and the other would need 1.5T space. The other space would be used to store other kinds of files like videos and “stuff” in general.)

I forgot to @muru ... you might not get a notification...

No, post owners always get notified. I'd get notified even if you were @-mentioning someone else. ZFS being overkill... well, you need a filesystem, and you need to preallocate some space for a file which in turn is used as an image which you'll then format and use as another filesystem. Well, zvols are block devices directly made from a ZFS filesystem - they show up as one in /dev/zvol/xyz! You can just carry on from the formatting step. So if a filesystem offers a feature that perfectly fits your use case, why not use it? If it has other features, great, you don't need to use them all.

I liked @muru 's answer. Playing around I found a couple of interesting findings that would be too long for a comment. So here are my two cents.
Tests with size and mkfs
mkfs makes a sparse file
Apparently mkfs makes the 100MB.bin file a sparse one by default
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=100MB.bin bs=1024 count=102400
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 1.54324 s, 67.9 MB/s

$ ls -sh 100MB.bin
100M 100MB.bin

$ mkfs -t ext4 100MB.bin
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Discarding device blocks: done
Creating filesystem with 102400 1k blocks and 25688 inodes
Filesystem UUID: cb3c57f4-0119-47da-b39e-4fbbff119a8e
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
    8193, 24577, 40961, 57345, 73729

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (4096 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

$ ls -sh 100MB.bin
320K 100MB.bin

$ du -h 100MB.bin
320K    100MB.bin

$ du --apparent-size -h 100MB.bin
100M    100MB.bin

$ rm 100MB.bin

mkfs with nodiscard
But apparently using nodiscard it doesn't convert the file to a sparse one. But it still reduces the 100MB.bin's size.
$ mkfs -t ext4 -E nodiscard 100MB.bin
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Creating filesystem with 102400 1k blocks and 25688 inodes
Filesystem UUID: dab15e3b-43fa-4242-9611-539ad6838f50
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
    8193, 24577, 40961, 57345, 73729

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (4096 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

$ du --apparent-size -h 100MB.bin
100M    100MB.bin

$ du -h 100MB.bin # But the disk usage is still less tham 100MB, weird?
96M 100MB.bin

$ rm 100MB.bin

The whole example with extra information
The same example as @muku 's answer but checking sizes along the way. Also using fallocate to punch holes and make what we did even sparser.
Check out the complete example without showing the output, can be pasted into a terminal directly or used to play around.
A couple of notes:

ls -sh 100MB.bin and du -h 100MB.bin return the same information (using a slightly different output).
I repeated some commands to show the status on different moments of the script.
All run on a Raspberry Pi 4, with Raspbian.

$ # Create a 100M file, filled with zeros
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=100MB.bin bs=1024 count=102400
102400+0 records in
102400+0 records out
104857600 bytes (105 MB, 100 MiB) copied, 1.67925 s, 62.4 MB/s

$ # Show the size used by 100MB.bin
$ ls -sh 100MB.bin
100M 100MB.bin

$ # Add a filesystem to 100MB.bin
$ mkfs -t ext4 100MB.bin
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Discarding device blocks: done
Creating filesystem with 102400 1k blocks and 25688 inodes
Filesystem UUID: f185f88f-20ef-4d28-b203-f3e6272c732b
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
    8193, 24577, 40961, 57345, 73729

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (4096 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done

$ # Show the size used by 100MB.bin
$ ls -sh 100MB.bin
320K 100MB.bin

$ # Show the apparent file size of 100MB.bin
$ du --apparent-size -h 100MB.bin
100M    100MB.bin

$ # Create a directory, used later for mounting
$ mkdir 100MB.mount

$ # Mount 100MB.bin inside 100MB.mount
$ # `sudo` needed
$ sudo mount 100MB.bin 100MB.mount

$ # Assigning the current user as owner for 100MB.mount
$ # recursively, sudo needed
$ sudo chown -R $USER 100MB.mount

$ # Show the size used by 100MB.bin
$ ls -sh 100MB.bin
324K    100MB.bin

$ # Using 1T instead of 1TB
$ # T=power of 1024, TB=power of 1000
$ truncate -s 1T 100MB.mount/1T_sparse

$ # Show the size used by 100MB.bin
$ ls -sh 100MB.bin
336K 100MB.bin

$ # Show the size used by 100MB.mount/1T_sparse
$ ls -sh 100MB.mount/1T_sparse
0 100MB.mount/1T_sparse

$ # Show the apparent file size of 100MB.mount/1T_sparse
$ du --apparent-size -h 100MB.mount/1T_sparse
1.0T    100MB.mount/1T_sparse

$ # Create a non sparse 50M file
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=100MB.mount/50M_nosparse bs=1024 count=51200
51200+0 records in
51200+0 records out
52428800 bytes (52 MB, 50 MiB) copied, 0.919962 s, 57.0 MB/s

$ # Show apparent size for 100MB.bin, 100MB.mount/1T_sparse and 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
$ du -h --apparent-size 100MB.bin; du -h --apparent-size 100MB.mount/1T_sparse; du -h --apparent-size 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
100M    100MB.bin
1.0T    100MB.mount/1T_sparse
50M 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse

$ # Show used space for 100MB.bin, 100MB.mount/1T_sparse and 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
$ ls -sh 100MB.bin; ls -sh 100MB.mount/1T_sparse; ls -sh 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
51M 100MB.bin
0 100MB.mount/1T_sparse
51M 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse

$ # Try adding 100MB of zeros to 100MB.mount/1T_sparse
$ # An error ocurrs because there is not space left in 100MB.mount
$ # Which is actually 100MB.bin mounted
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=100MB.mount/1T_sparse bs=1024 skip=102400 count=102400 conv=notrunc
dd: error writing '100MB.mount/1T_sparse': No space left on device
35135+0 records in
35134+0 records out
35977216 bytes (36 MB, 34 MiB) copied, 0.550553 s, 65.3 MB/s

$ # Show apparent size for 100MB.bin, 100MB.mount/1T_sparse and 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
$ du -h --apparent-size 100MB.bin; du -h --apparent-size 100MB.mount/1T_sparse; du -h --apparent-size 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
100M    100MB.bin
1.0T    100MB.mount/1T_sparse
50M 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse

$ # Show used space for 100MB.bin, 100MB.mount/1T_sparse and 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
$ ls -sh 100MB.bin; ls -sh 100MB.mount/1T_sparse; ls -sh 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
85M 100MB.bin
35M 100MB.mount/1T_sparse
51M 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse

$ # Using fallocate to "punch holes" where there were a bunch of zeros
$ fallocate -d 100MB.mount/1T_sparse; fallocate -d 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse

$ # Show apparent size for 100MB.bin, 100MB.mount/1T_sparse and 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
$ du -h --apparent-size 100MB.bin; du -h --apparent-size 100MB.mount/1T_sparse; du -h --apparent-size 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
100M    100MB.bin
1.0T    100MB.mount/1T_sparse
50M 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse

$ # Show used space for 100MB.bin, 100MB.mount/1T_sparse and 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
$ ls -sh 100MB.bin; ls -sh 100MB.mount/1T_sparse; ls -sh 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
85M 100MB.bin
0 100MB.mount/1T_sparse
0 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse

$ # Unmount 100MB.mount
$ sudo umount 100MB.mount

$ # Using fallocate to "punch holes" where there were a bunch of zeros
$ fallocate -d 100MB.bin

$ # Mount 100MB.bin inside 100MB.mount
$ # `sudo` needed
$ sudo mount 100MB.bin 100MB.mount

$ # Show apparent size for 100MB.bin, 100MB.mount/1T_sparse and 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
$ du -h --apparent-size 100MB.bin; du -h --apparent-size 100MB.mount/1T_sparse; du -h --apparent-size 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
100M    100MB.bin
1.0T    100MB.mount/1T_sparse
50M 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse

$ # Show used space for 100MB.bin, 100MB.mount/1T_sparse and 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
$ ls -sh 100MB.bin; ls -sh 100MB.mount/1T_sparse; ls -sh 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse
4.0M 100MB.bin
0 100MB.mount/1T_sparse
0 100MB.mount/50M_nosparse

